# AS3 Gestouch: TransformGesture on container with children using Pangesture

Tags: actionscript-3

I got a container with a dynamic number of children sprites. Each child uses a Gestouch PanGesture to allow the user to move it around within the container.

I would like to invoke a Gestouch TransFormGesture on the container so that I can zoom and pan it (pan using two fingers). I have a setup currently with a TransformGesture on the stage. My problem is naturally that if the user wants to zoom or pan, and sets down their first finger onto one of the child objects, that child's PanGesture starts. With my current setup the user would have to aim in between the children to successfully start the TransformGesture

I'd love it if anyone could enlighten me as to what would be a good strategy for solving this? Slop on the PanGesture? Is it wrong to use a PanGesture like I do? Something more elegant?

Answer (score 0):

Dude, I really don't think there are many Gestouch adepts here.

https://github.com/fljot/Gestouch/issues/66